# Twig template inheritance from bundle folder

Tags: symfony, templates, twig

I'm using a template which inheritates from another template  the base template it's on the MyBundle/view folder (like the child template) but its not found ,only works if the base template its on App/resource/views folder

```
{% extends 'src/UserBundle/Resources/views/User/base1.html.twig' %}
{% block body %}
  <ul id="navigation">
      {% for user in users %}
          <li>{{ user.getUsername }}</li>
      {% endfor %}
  </ul>
{% endblock %}
```

works with

```
{% base1.html.twig' %} //looks for base1 on App/Resources/views
```

It's mandatory to place the base templates on app/resouces/views or can I place it in myBundle/resources/views?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the super template is in a bundle you have to extend it like this:

```
{% extends 'UserBundle:User:base1.html.twig' %}
```